# Вычисление оценки подобия. Нужно как-то вычислять коэффициент общности для множества векторов

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, машинное-обучение, искусственный-интеллект

Как выявлять среди набора векторов максимально похожие?

Мне нужно обнаруживать устойчивые и повторяющиеся паттерны среди всего набора векторов, чтобы на них обучать уже сеть. 
Таким образом хочу построить наиболее корректный датасет исключив из обучения случайные вбросы, признавая неповторяющиеся вектора шумом. Обнаружив что вектор не повторяется, я должен установить целевое значение = 0 *(это первый символ в строке)*.

Пример датасета выложил по ссылке: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bVp5m852g9G3rt-VUvwhA5l-Jsrxy5wd/view?usp=sharing
(По аналогии с MNIST, первое значение в строке является целевым.)

P.S. Я пробовал обучить один персептрон и прогнать по всем векторам. Там где он активируется считал вектора похожими. Но что-то пошло не так. Он почти на всех векторах срабатывает.

Пробовал также вычислять расстояние джаккарда, но не уверен что это правильное применение. Вот пример кода:

```html
# Расстояние джаккарда
import scipy.spatial.distance as dist
distance=[]

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.iloc[index,0] != bws:
      list1 = list(row[1:])
  
      for index2, row2 in df.iloc[index+1:,1:].iterrows():
        if df.iloc[index2,0] != bws:
          list2 = list(row2)
          distance.append(dist.pdist([list1,list2], 'jaccard'))

print('длина массива:', len(distance), '\tmax:', max(distance), '\tmin:', min(distance), '\tmean:', np.mean(distance))
```

Answer (score 0):

Задача "*обнаруживать устойчивые и повторяющиеся паттерны среди всего набора векторов*" - официально называется задачей кластеризации. Результат кластеризации - разбиение входных объектов на группы максимально похожих между собой объектов. В дальнейшем их можно использовать и для задачи классификации.

Побочным результатом кластеризации есть выявление выбросов в данных, т.е. выявление таких объектов, которых во-первых существенно мало, а во вторых, которые существенно отличаются от остальных. При желании, их можно считать шумом.

Самостоятельно "городить огород" можно, но разуменее использовать готовые методы кластеризации из scikit-learn.  Их там много, подбирать надо по задаче.

Comment: А вы не могли бы привести пример на демо-наборе?
Например у меня вот такие вектора: http://kramer.su/media/cms_page_media/downloads/dataset.csv Ну или если удобно то на наборе MNIST

Comment: Какой именно метод кластеризации вы хотели-бы видеть в виде примера? Просто если "все" или "любой" то проще открыть соответствующий учебник. И еще. В вашем "демо-наборе" присутствуют столбцы с единственным значением. Совершенно очевидно, что никакой ценности для задачи кластеризации-классификации они не несут в принципе. Так что первый шаг - традиционно  -  очистка данных.

Comment: к сожалению я не знаком с современными алгоритмами кластеризации и подобрать тем более подходящий способ выше моих возможностей. Я почистил данные, там 1000 строк http://zdek.ru/dataset_corr1000.csv  Вы можете порекомендовать наиболее подходящий способ кластеризации для моего набора данных?